When In VSCODE I want to view the breadcrumb of XML tags or use "Go To Parent Fold" in a XML Document
When using VSCODE and attempt to jump to a parent tag it fails to land on that tag.
AWC_HiddenCommands->Parent Fold
When I stand on "AWC_HiddenCommands" and "Go  To Parent FOLD", the results are not as expected. Maybe I'm doing something incorrect? Am I standing in the wrong location? on a tag name? tag line?
Does the "Go To Parent FOLD" not work for XML files with Carriage returns (new lines) within a tag?
Simple test fails - stand on Child2, go to parent fold results in "returns"
<parent>
    <child1/>
    <child2>
TEXT (Text starts in column 1, and this is the resulting "Go To Parent Fold" Command and not the "parent" tag as expected)
    </child2>
    <child3> (Stand on this line |, and select Ctrl+Shift+p, and then Select Go To Parent Fold)
    </child3>
</parent>


can you please provide a textual repro with an expected and actual results, using a | character to represent the cursor position?

Not sure what your asking, but the image explains it. For some reason when I tried to enter the example it continues to think it's code and an example:




THIS
IS
TEXT
STARTING in the 1st column.
    
|
    

please [edit]. also, I asked for three pieces. that's only one. 1) starting state 2) desired "after" state 3) actual "after" state
